# Heap Leak in a cpp code

Tags: c++, pointers, graph, heap-memory, delete-operator

I am doing a project named wireless Network Toplogy. It use graphs as a data structure. I have make pointers but am facing heap leak problems. Please can anyone help fix this error? Where to call the delete operator? The cpp code is attached:

---

```
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "myGraph.h"
#include "wirelessNetwork.h"
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    /* First part of the experiments */
    for (int i = 500; i <= 950; i += 50)
    {
        wirelessNetwork *g = new wirelessNetwork(10, i);
        std::cout <<  (L"For network with n=") << i <<  (L": ") << std::endl;
        double average = (static_cast<double>(g->graph->numEdges) / (static_cast<double>(g->graph->numVertices)));
        std::cout <<  (L"    The average degree is ") << average << std::endl;
        std::cout <<  (L"    The maximum degree is ") << g->getMaxDegree() << std::endl;

        /* Perform topology control */
        g->topologyControl();
        std::cout <<  (L"  After topology control: ") << std::endl;
        average = (static_cast<double>(g->graph->numEdges)) / (static_cast<double>(g->graph->numVertices));
        std::cout <<  (L"    The average degree is ") << average << std::endl;
        std::cout <<  (L"    The maximum degree is ") << g->getMaxDegree() << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }



    /* Second part of the experiments */
    wirelessNetwork *g = new wirelessNetwork(10, 1000);
    std::cout <<  (L"***********************************") << std::endl;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        /* Randomly pick two vertices as the source and destination */
        int i1 = static_cast<int>(1000 * rand());
        int i2 = static_cast<int>(1000 * rand());
        string nameTemp = "a";
        string node1 = nameTemp + std::to_string(i1); 
        string  node2 = nameTemp + std::to_string(i2);

//ORIGINAL LINE: String[] route = g.compassRouting(node1, node2);
         string *route = g->compassRouting(node1, node2);
        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout <<  (L"Path generated from ") << node1 <<  (L" to ") << node2 <<  (L":") << std::endl;
        for (int k = 0; k < route->length(); k++)
        {
            std::cout <<  (L" ") << route[k];
        }
        if (node2 != route[route->length() - 1])
        {
            std::cout << std::endl;
            std::cout <<  (L" No route found...") << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout <<  (L" Length of the path generated is ") << (route->length() - 1) << std::endl;
    }


    /* Third part of the experiments */
    g->topologyControl();
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout <<  (L"***********************************") << std::endl;
    std::cout <<  (L"After topology control...") << std::endl;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        int i1 = static_cast<int>(1000 * rand());
        int i2 = static_cast<int>(1000 * rand());
        string nameTemp = "a";
        string node1 = nameTemp + std::to_string(i1);
        string  node2 = nameTemp + std::to_string(i2);
//ORIGINAL LINE: String[] route = g.compassRouting(node1, node2);
        string *route = g->compassRouting(node1, node2);
        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout <<  (L"Path generated from ") << node1 <<  (L" to ") << node2 <<  (L":") << std::endl;
        for (int k = 0; k < route->length(); k++)
        {
            std::cout <<  (L" ") << route[k];
        }
        if (node2 != route[route->length() - 1])
        {
            std::cout << std::endl;
            std::cout <<  (L" No route found...");
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout <<  (L" Length of the path is ") << (route->length() - 1) << std::endl;
    }

}
`
```

Comment: since you have no `delete` in your code what exactly did you try first? take as a rule of thumb: for every `new` you should have a `delete`.

Comment: i did add delete for every new still it breaks

Comment: as far as I see you have no need for pointers in your code (correct me if I'm wrong) so try this: replace all your `wirelessNetwork *g = new wirelessNetwork(...);` statements with `wirelessNetwork g(...);` (and adjust pointer access). Maybe read up on [dynamic memory](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/)

Comment: Besides all answers and comments, try using a smart pointer like 'unique_ptr' and 'auto_ptr'. They take care of de-allocation when going out of scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of identifying when to call delete operator is to check when that pointer variable goes out of scope and to delete it just before it goes out of scope.

```
void func()
{
   ClassA* ptr1 = new ClassA;

   //do NULL check for ptr1 and do stuff

   delete ptr1;
   //here ptr1 will lose scope. 
   //If not deleted, it will become a memory leak.
}
```

There can be scenarios where we cannot delete a pointer even if it goes out of scope. For example if we store the new pointer value in some other pointer variable, and the 2nd variable is still not out of scope.

```
void func(bool IsReady)
{
    ClassA* ptr1 = NULL;
    if(IsReady)
    {
        ClassA* ptr2 = new ClassA;
        //do stuff
        ptr1 = ptr2;
        //in this case, even though ptr2 will lose scope outside this block, 
        //the ptr2 value is assigned to ptr1 which is does not lose scope outside this block.
    }
    //here ptr1 will still contain the data we copied in the if block, 
    //else it will be NULL. After use of ptr1 is complete, do a NULL check and delete.
    if(ptr1 != NULL)
        delete ptr1;
}
```

In your case I see only the first type, and only 2 places the new operator is called. 
Have called the delete operator at the appropriate place for the first case, just before g goes out of scope:

```
/* First part of the experiments */
for (int i = 500; i <= 950; i += 50)
{
    wirelessNetwork *g = new wirelessNetwork(10, i);
    std::cout <<  (L"For network with n=") << i <<  (L": ") << std::endl;
    double average = (static_cast<double>(g->graph->numEdges) / (static_cast<double>(g->graph->numVertices)));
    std::cout <<  (L"    The average degree is ") << average << std::endl;
    std::cout <<  (L"    The maximum degree is ") << g->getMaxDegree() << std::endl;

    /* Perform topology control */
    g->topologyControl();
    std::cout <<  (L"  After topology control: ") << std::endl;
    average = (static_cast<double>(g->graph->numEdges)) / (static_cast<double>(g->graph->numVertices));
    std::cout <<  (L"    The average degree is ") << average << std::endl;
    std::cout <<  (L"    The maximum degree is ") << g->getMaxDegree() << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    //here g loses scope and does not seem to be stored in any other pointer
    delete g;
}
```

For the second case, call delete at the end of the function.

Hope this solves your issue of when to call the delete in your code.

However, you can avoid calling both new and delete in your case by replacing:

```
wirelessNetwork *g = new wirelessNetwork(10, i);
```

with

```
wirelessNetwork g(10, i);
```

And for accessing the member variables use g. instead of g->. 
For example: `g->topologyControl();` should be `g.topologyControl();`

Hope this answer helps.

Answer (score 1):

The best answer is you shouldn't be using pointers or the new operator.  As others suggested, just construct the object directly in the scope where it is needed, so it will be destroyed automatically when it goes out of scope.

A very common (but I think very poor) answer to this question, is to delete the object immediately before the pointer goes out of scope and/or put all your delete operations at the same nesting level as the corresponding new operations.  As in this case, when that approach is practical, you almost always didn't need the pointer or the new at all.  When it is not practical for the lifetime of the object to match the scope in which it is created, then you really need a pointer and use of the new operator and managing the lifetime of the object is one of the harder aspects of C++ programming.  There are no generic answers in those cases.  But until you have such a problem, don't create it by pointless use of the new operator.